tvOS keyboard focus with swiftUI
I'm trying to find a solution used in AppleTV app or YouTube app. When the user navigates to search results, the keyboard is getting hidden. I've tried using searchable modifier, but it seems it's not working. I'm trying to achieve something similar to the one in the image.
Code not working:
struct SearchView: View {

@State var searchTerm: String = ""

var sortedMatchingAssets: [String] {
   [
    "aaa1", "bbb1", "ccc1", "aaa2", "bbb2", "ccc2", "aaa3", "bbb3", "ccc3", "aaa4", "bbb4", "ccc4",
    "aaa5", "bbb5", "ccc5", "aaa6", "bbb6", "ccc6", "aaa7", "bbb7", "ccc7", "aaa8", "bbb8", "ccc8",
    "aaa9", "bbb9", "ccc9", "aahtra", "bgrebb", "ccgreac", "aagweaa", "bbbfw", "cafwecc", "aafewa", "bbfweavb", "caw23cc",
    "aaa10", "bbb10", "ccc10", "aaa14", "bbb14", "ccc14", "aaa15", "bbb", "ccc15", "aaa16", "bbb16", "ccc16",
    "aaa11", "bbb11", "ccc11", "aaa17", "bbb17", "ccc17", "aaa18", "bbb18", "ccc18", "aaa19", "bbb19", "ccc19",
    "aaa12", "bbb12", "ccc12", "aaa20", "bbb20", "ccc20", "aa21a", "bb21b", "ccc21", "21a21aa", "b22bb", "22ccc",
    "aaa13", "bbb13", "ccc13", "aa31a", "4bbb", "c22cc", "aad2a", "bb11b", "ccg3c", "a12aa", "bf32bb", "c32cc"
   ]
}

var suggestedSearchTerms: [String] {
    guard !searchTerm.isEmpty else { return [] }
    return sortedMatchingAssets.filter { $0.contains(searchTerm) }
}

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
       HStack {
            ForEach(sortedMatchingAssets, id: \.self) { asset in
                Button {

                } label: {
                    Text(asset)
                }
            }
        }
       .background(.red)
    }
    .scrollClipDisabled()
    .searchable(text: $searchTerm)
    .searchSuggestions {
        ForEach(suggestedSearchTerms, id: \.self) { suggestion in
            Text(suggestion)
        }
    }
    .background(.blue)
}


